# PHP openssl_error

Tags: php, openssl

I have created a web interface where a user's forgotten password will be emailed to his registered email account. Everything works fine in my localhost server but when I uploaded my php file to a host domain, emails no longer send.

Initially the code also didn't work in my localhost but then I turned on the php_openssl option in my php.ini file and everything worked great. I think now the same thing is happening in my host domain, and I need to turn on the php_openssl option.

But I cannot find any option in cPanel to do this.

[image: cPanel screenshot showing OpenSSL support is disabled]

How do I enable this option in cPanel?

Comment: Contact your host on how to enable the option. You can check to see if it's installed/enabled by creating a page that just has <?php phpinfo(); ?> and browsing to that page.

Comment: _Don't do that_.  **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: Yes great , password should be encrypted but i am just trying to do email scripting in my hosted server but i couldn't do it...

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. done any basic debugging yourself to figure out WHY it's not working? you've provided absolutely no useful details, so at best we can make wild guesses. I'm blaming aliens.

Answer (score 1):

To enable php_openssl you need to open your php.ini file and uncomment the line

> ;extension=php_openssl.dll

By removing the ";" before that.

To know your php.ini file. Try

> php --ini

You will see the php.ini file location like /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Open the filw with a editor like vi

> vi /usr/local/lib/php.ini

then uncomment the line extension=php_openssl.dll

If there is no line like that simply append the line to the php.ini

Thats it. :)